# Initialise foundaiton 6 orbit if there are more than 4 slides

Tags: jquery, orbit, zurb-foundation-6

I have the following markup:

```
<section class="projects-holder">
  <ul class="">
    <li class="single-project"> Porject-1 </li>
    <li class="single-project"> Project-2 </li>
    <li class="single-project"> Project-3 </li>
    <li class="single-project"> Project-4 </li>
    <li class="single-project"> Project-5 </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

with its CSS:

```
.projects-holder ul{height:inherit; margin-left:0;}
.projects-holder img{margin-top: 20px;}
.projects-holder li{ 
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: #faa;
  min-height: 100px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {

    .projects-holder {overflow: hidden; height:100%;}

    .projects-holder li{    
        height: 100%;
        width: 25%;
        float: left;
        list-style-type: none;
        border-right: 1px solid #333;
    }

}
```

and its js:

```
$(document).foundation();

if($('.projects-holder li').length == 4){
    console.log('no need for caorusel');
}
else{
    var elem = new Foundation.Orbit($('.projects-holder'));
    console.log(elem);
}
```

I was expecting that I could slide to the 5th slide but it doesn't happen.. I thought this would take care of all the calculations: `var elem = new Foundation.Orbit($('.projects-holder'));`